# How to change x,y axis' "VALUE" colors & fonts

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

I digged a lot over the internet and I managed to change them for a Pie Chart with "entryTextStyle:" property:

```
Expanded(
    child: charts.PieChart(_wifiData,
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        behaviors: [
          charts.DatumLegend(
            outsideJustification:
                charts.OutsideJustification.endDrawArea,
            horizontalFirst: false,
            desiredMaxRows: 2,
            cellPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
            entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                    kWifiPieChart2)),
          )
        ],
        defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
            arcWidth: 100,
            arcRendererDecorators: [
              charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                labelPosition:
                    charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside,
                insideLabelStyleSpec:
                    charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        color: charts
                            .MaterialPalette.white,
                        fontSize: 20),
              )
            ])),
  ),
```

However I could not find the proper way to do it for Line Chart and Bar Chart. The parts I would like to adjust are the ones highlighted with yellow markers:

[image]

[image]

Here are my codes:
Bar Chart:

```
Expanded(
    child: charts.BarChart(
      barChartData,
      animate: true,
      barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    ),
  ),
```

For Line Chart :

```
Expanded(
    child: charts.LineChart(lineChartData,
        defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
            areaOpacity: 0.4,
            includeArea: true,
            stacked: true),
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        behaviors: [
          charts.ChartTitle('2020 Yılı',
              titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                  color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                      kIbbWifiPieChart2)),
              behaviorPosition:
                  charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
              titleOutsideJustification: charts
                  .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
          charts.ChartTitle('1000 Kullanıcı',
              titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                  color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                      kIbbWifiPieChart2)),
              behaviorPosition:
                  charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
              titleOutsideJustification: charts
                  .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
          charts.ChartTitle(
            'Eğitim Durumu',
            titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                    kIbbWifiPieChart2)),
            behaviorPosition:
                charts.BehaviorPosition.end,
            titleOutsideJustification: charts
                .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea,
          )
        ]),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to change the label colors:

It is done with

```
OrdinalAxisSpec(renderSpec:charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(labelStyle:... )
```

properties. Here is my code:

```
Expanded(
    child: charts.BarChart(
      _barChartData,
      animate: true,
      barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
          labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                kIbbWifiPieChart2),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
          labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
            color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                kIbbWifiPieChart2),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```